# how to refer a previous transaction in current transaction in ethereum private blockchain

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum

I am trying to build an private block chain based use case (not a financial one) to benefit from the decentralized nature of BC. The scenario is something like this, there are multiple nodes connected to the chain and deploy smart contracts onto the network. The smart contract basically has two functions one is getAccess and other is grantAccess. The getAccess function of a contract (deployed by node1 for example) is called by node 2 and an event is associated with getAccess that gets triggered. Upon this event, node1 should call the grantAccess function of the smart contract deployed by node 2. In this call, it should pass transaction ID of getAccess as argument so it is understandable by the network that node1 is replying to the getAccess request. How can i pass transaction ID as an argument to the function of smart contract is my question.

Thanks

Comment: nodes do not call contracts, nodes process transactions (all at the same time, the same transaction). anyone with an account, (regardless of which node does process the transaction ) can send money to your contracts and they are going to be executed. So, please edit your question to fix this misunderstanding of the Ethereum concept. Also, please explain what parameters do your functions receive and what do they return or should return (besides tx hash which you mentioned). A sample code would be great.

Comment: Hi I understand your comment about nodes and accounts. I don't know what is the best way to write it. In my scenario, I creates 5 nodes and made them up to mine on the network. Using the accounts of nodes I deployed contracts, in my case,to keep it simple I had one account for one node.

Comment: Well, first of all in Ethereum transaction is not an ID, i.e. a number like in MySQL , it is a string and it is called transaction hash. Second, the contract can not access the transaction hash, simply because a transaction can be submitted and become a pending transaction, so, it doesn't belong to any block yet. But if you edit your question to explain what exactly are you trying to achieve and what does "access granted" mean in your case, maybe somebody could suggest an alternative solution. I suspect what you really need is the transaction sender, not the id , and this variable is available

Comment: Hi, the thign i want to work on is there are 5 parties which hold set of devices with them. These parties are connected to blockchain (called nodes in BC terminology). Any device under a node (node2) want access to device under other node (node1), node2 should place a transaction called getAccess, where it gives the details like consumer ID and node1 should provide a token for this request on BC. while the node1 places grantAccess transaction on BC, i thought it can take one argument transaction hash (of getAccess transaction), but from your explanation it seems not possible to do it that way